# Performance with webpack in Angular

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I can see some projects with `Webpack` and some are without `Webpack`. So, is there anything like that by using `Webpack`, we can improve performance ? I am using `Angular 4`. What is the exact use of `Webpack` in `Angular` project ?

Answer (score 0):

Try it out, and compare what you get with it that you don't have without it.

You'll see that your files will be bundled to reduce loading time and some other neat features.

https://webpack.github.io/docs/